# Finding collinearity among variables

Tags: statistics

I have been reading about how (multi)-collinearity among predictor variables can be determined by looking at the condition number, or smallest eigenvalue, of the covariance matrix. My question is, if you have the covariance matrix could you not just determine that there is collinearity by looking at the correlation coefficients between variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Econometric textbook authors like Theil, or Spanos, have advocated the use of partial correlation and multiple correlation coefficients between regressors, as a better way to detect multicollinearity, because these metrics are invariant to linear transformations of the data (condition number is not). But above all, I suggest you read chapter 7 of Maddala's textbook (2001), where he advances the argument that even these measures  are not the most relevant -and, being Maddala, he has the habit to showcase his point by convincing and fully worked-out examples. Essentially he helps the reader understand why this is a multidimensional problem (and so simple approaches like the one you think about are not enough). If you are interested in the Bayesian point of view, Leamer (1978) contains in a few pages the gist of the approach - and the book is [officially free to download.](http://www.anderson.ucla.edu/faculty/edward.leamer/books/specification_searches/specification_searches.htm)